# What is the difference between \lnot and \neg?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

As the title states, what is the difference between `\lnot` and `\neg`? The output seems the same to me but I want to know if they are the exact same thing, both semantically and as code definition.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\(\lnot a \, \neg a\)
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Similarly `\land` and `\wedge` represent the same symbol as do `\lor` and `\vee`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For your disappointment, none. They are the same.

If you run

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\(\show\lnot a \, \show\neg a\)
\end{document}
```

you'll get:

```
> \lnot=\mathchar"23A.
l.3 \(\show\lnot
                 a \, \show\neg a\)
? 
> \neg=\mathchar"23A.
l.3 \(\show\lnot a \, \show\neg
                                a\)
```

which shows that both are `\mathchar"23A`.

---

In fact, in `plain.tex` one finds:

```
\mathchardef\neg="023A \let\lnot=\neg
```

The same appears for other symbols as well:

```
\mathchardef\wedge="225E \let\land=\wedge
\mathchardef\vee="225F \let\lor=\vee
\def\neq{\not=} \let\ne=\neq
\mathchardef\leq="3214 \let\le=\leq
\mathchardef\geq="3215 \let\ge=\geq
\mathchardef\ni="3233 \let\owns=\ni
\mathchardef\leftarrow="3220 \let\gets=\leftarrow
\mathchardef\rightarrow="3221 \let\to=\rightarrow
```

My *guess* for the reason of this is that in different fields of applications these symbols get different names, so they have different names to make their utilization more intuitive.

---

In LaTeX, what happens is basically the same, but with a few more bells and whistles:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\neg}{\mathord}{symbols}{"3A}
    \let\lnot=\neg
```

This can be found in `fontmath.ltx` (loaded by `latex.ltx`).

Comment: I imagine that also semantically I could consider them the same, right?

Comment: Yes, both are defined to be the same character. It's just two names for the same thing.

Comment: There is another redefinition of them in `unicode-math`, as the Unicode character U+00AC. It also defines `\lnot` as an alias for `\neg`.

Comment: IIRC, ruby also has some under-the-hood-identical methods with different designations to, as @PhelypeOleinik said, _"...make their utilization more intuitive."_; that said, their documentation is usually nice enough to mention this.