# What changed related to \ne in TeXLive 2019?

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath, texlive-2019

Did something change related to `\ne` recenetly?

The MWE below in TeXLive 2018 yields the expected output

[image]

but with TeXLive 2019 (with all packages up to date as of today) I get

> `Argument of \ne  has an extra }.`

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\OldNe\ne

\RenewDocumentCommand{\ne}{o}{%
    \mathrel{\OldNe}
}

\begin{document}
$a \ne b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ne` is now `\protect\ne<space>`, so you need to use the `letltxmacro` package and `\LetLtxMacro\OldNe\ne`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Thanks. Works great. Please post a answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the last LaTeX release (October 2019) a lot of commands which are not usually supposed to expand were made robust, so `\ne`, which usually was `\not=`, now expands to `\protect\ne␣` (`\ne␣` is `\csname ne \endcsname`).

With `\let\OldNe\ne`, when your command does `\mathrel{\OldNe}`, `\OldNe` expands to `\protect\ne␣`, and now `\ne␣` is a macro delimited by a `]`, but a `}` is found before that, so TeX raises the `Argument of \ne  has an extra }` (note the extra space in the error message).

---

Usually, this would have worked, because `\ne␣` would expand to `\not=`.  However, `xparse` uses the command `\ne␣` as a temporary macro to grab the arguments of `\ne` so that in case you forget a `}` somewhere, the error message will show you something meaningful:

```
Runaway argument?
[oops 
! Paragraph ended before \ne  was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

(see that the error occurred while grabbing the argument of `\ne␣`) rather than expose some `xparse` internal that doesn't give a clue about the source of the error:

```
Runaway argument?
[oops 
! Paragraph ended before \__xparse_grab_delimited_argument_of_some_macro:w was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

---

To work around the issue, for the time being, load the `letltxmacro` and use `\LetLtxMacro\OldNe\ne` instead of `\let\OldNe\ne`. `\LetLtxMacro` takes care of the fact that `\ne` is now protected.  The 2020-10-01 release, the LaTeX kernel will feature a brand new `\NewCommandCopy`, which can be used the same way as `\LetLtxMacro` to copy commands without worrying about their definition.

Comment: Is there a document which list the commands that were changed?

Comment: @PeterGrill Not officially, as far as I know. We have the history of commits in the LaTeX2e repo (http://github.com/latex3/latex2e), but not officially compiled into a list. That's a good idea, though, we should probably have one. I'll let you know if one comes to exist.

Comment: Why is the protected version delimited by a `]`?

Comment: @siracusa I think that is a response to what ever it is the OP is doing, Peter is making a macro that takes an optional arg.

Comment: @siracusa to be honest I don't know yet. I'm traveling until tomorrow, so my debugging powers are limited. I thought it weird too, since (from the very little I know of `xparse`'s internals) there should not be a `\ne<space>` nor a `]`-delimited macro. I'll investigate when I can.

Comment: @siracusa Sorry, I completely forgot to reply your question.  `\ne␣` is used as a temporary macro to grab delimited arguments, so that runaway messages look like they were caused by the top-level `\ne` macro.  I added a note about that to the answer.

Comment: Is there a difference between `\ne` and `\neq`? Is there a reason I should use one and not the other?

Comment: @Rain No, in standard LaTeX `\ne` and `\neq` are identical, same as a few other symbols (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430678/134574)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks!