# Cannot use 'macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode error with xparse and pgfkeys

Tags: xparse, pgfkeys

I have the following not working code, where I'm trying to replace the standard `\title` command with one that sets a `pgf` key and then calls back to the original standard command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /mykeys/title/.append code = {\@oldtitle{#1}}
}
\let\@oldtitle\title
\makeatother

\RenewDocumentCommand\title{m}{\pgfkeys{/mykeys/title = {#1}}}

%\renewcommand\title[1]{\pgfkeys{/mykeys/title = {#1}}} % This works


\title{Hello}

\begin{document}
  Not working
\end{document}
```

I get a single error without any other information:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.18 \title{Hello}
```

If I comment the `\RenewDocumentCommand` line and replace it with the commented one, it works. If I leave alone the `\title` command, it works. So it's some strange interaction between `pgfkeys`, `xparse` and how `\title` is defined?

What's going on here? My ideal goal would be to make it work with the `xparse` line since I use `xparse` everywhere else in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\title` is a robust macro, so using `\let` to copy it will not work. Specifically, with `xparse` it breaks because the macro `\title␣` is redefined internally by xparse and it fails when you use `\@oldtitle` (there's an explanation [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516066/134574)).

Use `\NewCommandCopy` instead of `\let`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /mykeys/title/.append code = {\@oldtitle{#1}}
}
\NewCommandCopy\@oldtitle\title
\makeatother

\RenewDocumentCommand\title{m}{\pgfkeys{/mykeys/title = {#1}}}

% \renewcommand\title[1]{\pgfkeys{/mykeys/title = {#1}}} % This works

\title{Hello}

\begin{document}
  Not working
\end{document}
```

---

`\NewCommandCopy` is available from LaTeX 2020-10-01 onwards.  On older releases you can use `\LetLtxMacro` (from the `letltxmacro` package):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /mykeys/title/.append code = {\@oldtitle{#1}}
}
\LetLtxMacro\@oldtitle\title
\makeatother

\RenewDocumentCommand\title{m}{\pgfkeys{/mykeys/title = {#1}}}

% \renewcommand\title[1]{\pgfkeys{/mykeys/title = {#1}}} % This works

\title{Hello}

\begin{document}
  Not working
\end{document}
```

You can also use `\LetLtxMacro` in newer releases, of course, but `\NewCommandCopy` cover a large number of robust commands than `\LetLtxMacro`.

Comment: Thanks! However, I get Undefined control sequence over `\NewCommandCopy`. Is it a recent addition to `xparse`?

Comment: @gigabytes Not `xparse`, it's a new command in the LaTeX kernel (available if you use an updated TeX Live 2020 or MiKTeX). Otherwise load the `letltxmacro` package and use `\LetLtxMacro` instead

Comment: I've just installed MacTeX 2020 but I don't have that command. I think I'll go for `letltxmacro`, which works for me, thank you!

Comment: @gigabytes For completeness, I added the `letltxmacro` version.  MacTeX is based on TeXLive, so updating it (with `tlmgr update --self --all`) should (as far as I know) give you the new version.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try. But, do you have any idea on why I didn’t get the error of this question with TeXLive 2018?

Comment: @gigabytes Because `\title` (along with lots of other LaTeX macros which aren't supposed to be expandable) were made robust in 2019.  See [`ltnews30`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews30.pdf) on the robust commands and also [`ltnews32`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews32.pdf) on `\NewCommandCopy`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Why the heck can’t you `\let` a robust macro?

Comment: @Gaussler You can, but most often than not it breaks something.  For example, the robust `\title` macro expands to `\protect\title␣` (`\title␣` is `\csname title\space\endcsname`), so you have to also `\let\@oldtitle␣\title␣` for it to work properly. `\NewCommandCopy` and `\LetLtxMacro` to that for you

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I don’t quite understand. Why does `\let\@oldtitle=\title` not just cause `\@oldtitle` to expand to `\protect\title␣`, which then has the same meaning as before? We did not change the definition of `\title␣`.

Comment: @Gaussler I linked a post with an explanation in my answer ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516066/134574) for your convenience). Basically, `\title` was redefined by `xparse`, and `xparse` uses `\title␣` as an auxiliary macro to grab delimited arguments, so `\@oldtitle` expanding to `\protect\title␣` will cause havoc